# How to test automatically Web Performance and Load Test Project in Visual Studio 2012 ultimate version

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, performance-testing

I am using VS2012 Ultimate to creating Web performance test and Load test project.First I created sample web page application, in this web page two text box username and password and submit button.Then run the web test project, it build successful and click the add recording, automatically opened internet explorer then we enter the web application url manually and enter the username, password and submit. Then stop the recording, it will go to the project and processing, finally result is passed.But I want when i run the  web performance and Load test project and give only url then automatically enter username and password and submit. Please guide me.

Comment: What is the specific question. As written your question appears to ask for general guidance. Please describe what the test is doing now, why that is not what you want and what you want the test to do.

Comment: Run the Web Performance and Load Test project, i give only url, then i want  username, password and submit are automatically process.

Comment: Please explain what you want in great detail. The phrase "*then i want username, password and submit are automatically process*" could mean many things.

Comment: I am having two text boxes one for username, another one for password and one submit button, without manual entry for username, password and submit action,it can be run automatically

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done in the web test. You will have to go to web test URL where you have textboxes, expand the URL properties (Form Post Parameters), here you can change the input parameters. Also, you can bind this with the data source also, data source could be csv file. Please check data source and Form Post Parameters options.